# Converting <string, vector<double>> map to <string, double[]> map

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdarray

In C++ I have a `vector_map` of the form `<string, std::vector<double>>`. I need to change those vectors of doubles to arrays of doubles so that I get an `array_map` of the form `<string, double[]>`

The problem is that when doing so, the arrays for every element in the map are the same and their elements are different from those of the original vectors. What I have right now is this:

```
map<string, double*> array_map;
  for (auto it : vector_map){
    double temp_arr[size of it.second as a const];
    std::copy(it.second.begin(), it.second.end(), temp_arr);
    array_map.insert({it.first, temp_arr});
  }
```

Comment: why do you need this? You know that `std::vector<double>::data()` returns a `double*` that points to the data array?

Comment: Standard C++ does not support VLA anyways. You'll need to dynamically allocate the elements. If you dislike `std::vector<T>`, you still can use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead.

Comment: Why not `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>`? And do you really need the map to be ordered on the key, would a `std::unordered_map` work as well?

Comment: As for another problem with code like the one you show, besides the VLA issue, the array is ***local*** inside the loop. Each iteration its life-time will end and the pointer you store will become immediately invalid.

Comment: _"I have a `vector_map`"_ - There is no such type in the standard library so you should tell us where you got this type from. If you created the type yourself, show its definition.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the *actual* and *underlying* problem this code is supposed to solve. Why do you need a map of pointers? Why can't you use the pointer provided by the vector itself?

Comment: Why go back to a "C" style array where you lose all size information and memory managment? std::vector has a data method that returns the pointer to its internal data...